# Why do i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I read a file and add it to a list then read the list and split the strings and compare it and do somthing with it.
i get this exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

**Where should i correct my code?**

```
for (Productname m : listIP) {
        if (m.getIdentifier() == null || m.getProductname() == null) {
                addToNonSimilarList( m.getProductname());
        } else {
            String id = m.getIdentifier().replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", " ").toUpperCase();
            String product = m.getProductname().replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", " ").toUpperCase();
            id = id.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            product = product.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            if (!id.equalsIgnoreCase(product)) {
                if (id.contains(" X ") && product.contains(" X ")) {
                    String[] ide = id.split(" (?=X\\s*\\d+)");
                    String[] prod = product.split(" (?=X\\s*\\d+)");
                    System.out.println(m.getMnemonic());
                    if (ide.length > 0 && prod.length > 0 && ide[1].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(prod[1].trim())) {
                        String[] i = ide[0].split(" (?=\\d+)");
                        String[] p = prod[0].split(" (?=\\d+)");
                        if (i[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(p[0].trim())) {
                            //do nothing
                        } else {
                            addToNonSimilarList( m.getProductname());
                        }
                    } else {
                        addToNonSimilarList( m.getProductname());
                    }
                } else {
                    addToNonSimilarList( m.getProductname());

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this condition looks dodgy:

```
if (ide.length > 0 && prod.length > 0 
    && ide[1].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(prod[1].trim())) {
```

You're testing if there's at least *one* element in each, but you're using the *second* element in each.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect you either want to change the `length` conditions or the array indexes. I'd also split this method into shorter ones, and probably create well-named static variables with references to `Pattern` objects, for clarity...

EDIT: If you genuinely want to use the second element from each array, I'd suggest:

```
if (ide.length > 1 && prod.length > 1 
    && ide[1].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(prod[1].trim())) {
```

Comment: Yes i should check out if second element of this two `ide[1] prod[1]` are the same. **what is the better way?**

Comment: @itro: Well check that there are *at least two elements* in each array, instead of at least one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (ide.length > 0 && prod.length > 0 && ide[1].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(prod[1].trim()))
```

if the length is equal to one then the first element can be accessed by ide[0] and prod[0] however, you are using ide[1] and prod[1] respectively. That's where the error comes from

Comment: When i remove `ide.length > 0 && prod.length > 0` i get the same error.I need to check out the second element of every split.What is the best way?

Comment: you are assuming that the first element is the one getting processed so instead of ide[1] and prod[1] on the condition, use ide[0] and prod[0]